# VNC on headless Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvnc, headless

So I've been trying for the past day to get my Ubuntu server to boot to desktop without a monitor connected to it. If it doesn't boot to the desktop, the **vino** server won't start. Which in result makes the VNC server not start.

I've tried to add a dummy monitor, followed [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/28/configure-linux-to-boot-without-a-monitor/) tutorial (tried to change the folder where the `xorg.conf` file was in, to no avail), either it hangs in the boot screen, or it simply boots me to the login screen.

I have enabled automatic login for my user in the settings page and in the GDM config, so when a monitor is attached to my server, I'm automatically put to the desktop. But, when a monitor isn't attached, it opens the login screen where I have to manually click "Login" for the VNC server to start.

So I'm wondering if there is a good way of making a remote desktop connection to a headless Ubuntu server.

Comment: X server on your local machine and a SSH tunnel.

Comment: I'm sorry, would you care to elaborate? You mean like boot into the terminal, then start the x server? Or like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine)?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/147109/automatically-start-vnc-server-on-startup https://superuser.com/questions/184596/how-to-access-vnc-on-a-linux-server-without-having-been-logged-in-to-the-machine

Comment: Been following [this](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot) tutorial right now, and my VNC Server is started on boot, which is what I wanted. But when connecting to the server, it shows a weird screen [like this](http://i.imgur.com/iLfEFQH.png). Anyone got any suggestions on what might be causing this? Thanks again!

Comment: It seems that you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/195817).  You’re asking how to make a remote desktop connection to a headless Ubuntu server.  It seems that you want to know how to get the vino and VNC servers to start automatically on a headless Ubuntu server; if so, you should ask that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the weird screen you are getting: (placing this as answer because of rep needed ':D )

I think in order to solve the grey screen problem, you should try this:

`# apt-get install xubuntu-desktop xfce4`

from [this tutorial](https://www.namhuy.net/3106/install-vnc-server-ubuntu-14-04.html).

Hope this helps.

As a note for anyone else reaching this and having been confused and confounded in trying to get vncserver to actually boot: in [this](https://www.namhuy.net/3106/install-vnc-server-ubuntu-14-04.html) tutorial, the startup script does not actually start the vncserver on boot, but the tutorial followed by the OP does.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having issues trying to get vncserver to work on a headless xubuntu computer, although I did not experience the login issue; my install was basically fresh, not sure if that has anything to do with it. For me the computer would simply hang at startup without a monitor attached. Regardless, I found a very simple solution.

Make a backup of your default grub file:

`sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old`

Then edit the active grub file `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

And uncomment (remove '#') on `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`

Finally save, and then update grub `sudo update-grub` and restart without a monitor attached.

I saw some tutorials use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"` but this is what causes the issues for vnc users. Note that your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` line may differ with some necessary commands, add them back if you need to.